# Get HostName in .jtl file in Jmeter

Tags: ant, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using ANT (build tool) to run jmeter functional scripts. I want to get the hostname or website name where all my jmeter scripts are running.

I have checked the jmeter.properties file to do some changes but no luck but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed and I want to share solution.

I have uncommented the configuration in jmeter.properties.

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=true
```

so that the hostname will be written to the jtl file and from the jtl file, i got it by xpath as below,

```
/testResults/httpSample/@Host
```

Thats it, you can use this as xsl variable for reporting or for any purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below inbuilt functions in JMeter.

- `${__machineName}` - to get the machine name
- `${__machineIP}` - to get the IP address